# Resolving TypeScript React JS Lint: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency without using comment to disable lint or without passing dependency

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lint

I am build a Web application using React JS and TypeScript. I am using React hooks. I created a custom hook and using that in a Component and calling a function of that hook inside that useEffect hook within the component as follow.

```
const Products: FC<{}> = () => {
  const productsHook = useProducts();

  useEffect(() => {
    productsHook.fetchProducts();
  }, []);
```

When I run lint, I am getting the following warning.

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'productsHook'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

When I add the following line,

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

right after this line, `productsHook.fetchProducts();`, it resolves the warning.

The other way to resolve the issue it to add `productsHook.fetchProducts` as an array element in the second parameter of `useEffect` like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
        productsHook.fetchProducts();
      }, [productsHook.fetchProducts]);
```

But, technically, it is unnecessary to do that. It will work perfectly fine if we don't do that too. Is there a way to resolve that warning without the comment to ignore or without passing the dependency in the second parameter of `useEffect`?

Answer (score 1):

I would just do it the second way, adding the function to the dependency array. It is for instance what is recommended to do when using `dispatch` in Redux, even though the `dispatch` function is guaranteed to always be the same, eslint cannot detect that, and the easiest way to solve it is to add it to the dependency array.
It's definitely a better option than getting into the habit of disabling warnings that you don't like.